# Is this a Masonic Ring?

Tags: world-war-two, military, 20th-century, europe, united-kingdom

I told by my Auntie that she had a Masonic ring that came from my Great Grandfather from my mum’s side of the family and I’m skeptical if this ring she sent a photo of is really a Masonic ring. I asked her who told you this is a Masonic ring and she said my Uncle told her this. Unfortunately I can’t upload the photo due to some errors I keep coming across. But I’ll bulletpoint on what it looks like.

- it has a crown
- background black
- shape of ring oval
- has funny writing on it
- it looks like an old British royal ring

That’s all I can pin down. Is there anyone that is a Masonic scholar or has Masonic knowledge about this?

I’m not saying that the picture I got from my Antie is an actual Masonic ring. The ring looks very royalist like. It has the words ”RE ME” It also has a symbol of a horse under the crown and the horse is chained to a ball.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess (since we don't have an actual picture of the ring yet), does the symbol resemble this?

[image]

If so your family member may have been a member of the [Royal Electrical and Mechanical Engineers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Electrical_and_Mechanical_Engineers). Note there are quite a few links in the [reference section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Electrical_and_Mechanical_Engineers#References) at the end of the Wikipedia article which may help you discover more about what your great grandfather may have been part of.

Comment: Holy shit!!! It looks exactly like that!!! That answers everything. My uncle said that my grandfather and his brothers were Masons and he and his brothers as the masons called each other helped each other to get decent jobs. But I never knew. I'll start questioning my anti and uncle about this. Thank you for the information.